# What is the difference between "happy to hear that" and "happy to hear this"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, this-that

Let's say I've sold a product to a customer.

A bit later the costumer tells me "wow, this is fantastic".

Now, do I better answer with "Thanks, I am glad to hear that" or "Thanks, I am glad to hear this"?

What's more correct?

Comment: Grammatically, they're both perfectly acceptable. Conversationally, I'd rarely use 'this' - probably only when the news is really detailed, and/or startling, and/or of a very personal nature. 'That' is the more prosaic (and thus unmarked, more natural sounding) choice. Here, choosing 'this' might convey the impression you're very surprised that the product is so good. Which is probably not what you wish to do.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'll use *that*, just because I'm not the person saying *it*.

From my perspective, the pronoun *that* is introducing a clause. Let's see the situation:

> (1) Costumer: Wow, this [product, which is close to me, the costumer] is fantastic.
>
> (2) Salesman: Thanks, I am glad to hear *that* (the product is fantastic).

If we changed *that* for *this* in (2):

> Salesman: Thanks, I am glad to hear *this* (the product is fantastic). -Obviously wrong.

OR

> Salesman: Thanks, I am glad to hear *this* (statement from you). -Obviously forced.

Another possibility is that *that* is not introducing a clause but being used instead of a phrase.

> Salesman: Thanks, I am glad to hear 'this is fantastic' [that].

Even another reason, for me, is that in (1), the speaker says *this*. Then, the listener can't refer to it (the product) with the same *this*, but with *that* because the speaker (Costumer) imposes his relation to the object of predication (the product), leaving the other part without the possibility to address the object in the same way (i.e., next to or in relation to the salesman).

Comment: What do you mean by BRB?

Comment: BRB = Be Right Back. I needed to leave the keyboard. I could have typed AFK (Absent From Keyboard), also.

Comment: I don't know why you couldn't have just waited before submitting the answer. There are no extra points for submitting an incomplete answer quickly as opposed to a complete answer later.

Comment: Should I say sorry? May I ask your forgiveness, great lord? Was it an unsavory and seedy deed, by which I deserve all hell's fire?

Comment: There is no need to take offense. The initial answer you posted was "I'll use that, just because I'm not the person saying it. From my perspective, the pronoun that is BRB"— which might have attracted downvotes or even moderation flags for deletion. Many participants here will leave a "quick response" as a comment, then return with a complete answer when they have time later. If you are unfamiliar with the Stack Exchange model, I suggest reviewing the [Help Center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: No offense taken. I though you where the one offended by my lack of patience.

Comment: Your answer before the "OR" part doesn't make sense to me. In "I am glad to hear that/this" "that" and "this" are pronouns. Pronouns don't introduce the clause "the product is fantastic", that would be the job of "that" as a conjunction. So it really doesn't make sense to compare "that" and "this" as if they're conjunctions, as you seem to have done: "Thanks, I am glad to hear this (the product is fantastic). -Obviously wrong." Both are demonstrative pronouns, and it's just a matter of which one of the two is preferable. You only really touched on this in the very last paragraph.